# How can i get the network tab with python requests?

Tags: python, networking, python-requests

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://' + "185.169.198.98:3128",
    'https': 'http://' + "185.169.198.98:3128",
}
r = requests.get(url,verify=True,headers=headers,proxies=proxies)
```

i want to get the network data like in the browser but with requests

[Image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlfOc.png)

Comment: You can get all that data, how you get it depends on what you want. You can get the headers with `r.headers`.

Comment: what actually do you want from network tab through `requests`

Comment: i wants the Media link. (see img) but the link is changing any time im sending a request

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will be possible to capture this with `requests`, but you can try to do this with `selenium wire`:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver  # Import from seleniumwire  

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver  
driver = webdriver.Firefox()  

# Go to the Google home page  
driver.get('https://www.google.com')  

# Access and print requests via the `requests` attribute  
for request in driver.requests:  
    if request.response:  
        print(  
            request.url,  
            request.response.status_code,  
            request.response.headers['Content-Type'])
```